# Phpdoc is not defined, but -V is work

Tags: php, composer-php, phpdoc

I installed the phpdocumentator via composer.

But I have an error:
[image]

Command `php composer.phar phpdoc -V` is work

And yet I did not understand the message: `No composer.json in current directory...` But it is now in this directory. -ls confirms this fact

Comment: the `-V` option skip any parameters (you could try with some other strange words)

Comment: @Matteo You're right. Command `php composer.phar phpdoc -h` shows the same error.

Comment: I think it's because of the dependencies. I do not have graphviz installed...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be executing phpdoc this way:
`./vendor/bin/phpdoc -d env/production -t env/autodoc` ?

Your command appears to only be calling the `-V` version option of `composer.phar`, and doing nothing whatsoever with regard to `phpdoc`.